# How do I upgrade an existing Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I have an existing Flutter app that I built half a year ago. I checked on `pubspec.lock`, it has this line:

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.10.0-110 <2.11.0"
  flutter: ">=1.16.0 <2.0.0"
```

So I assume the app was built for Flutter v1.16.

1. How do I upgrade this app to use the latest Flutter version? Running "flutter doctor" gives me `[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630], locale en-US)`, so my SDK is already updated to the latest version.
2. Interestingly, when I create a new app from scratch, the `pubspec.lock` does not have any information about Flutter's version. The same section now contains only this: `sdks: dart: ">=2.10.0-110 <2.11.0"`. In the future, how would I know which version was this app running?

I have tried running "flutter upgrade" within my app, but that was to upgrade the SDK, not the Flutter version of the app. So how do I upgrade my app to use the latest Flutter version? Or is it always built using the latest version of the SDK? Can't I target my app to build with a specific version of Flutter?

Answer (score 50):

> The following steps requires dart `2.19` tool or lower because the dart
> migrate tool is removed in version 3:

To update the project to null safety follow these steps:

Side note: change the flutter version in `pubsec.yaml`, make new project and copy the following line:

```
sdk: ">=2.19.6 <3.0.0"
```

Then follow the steps:

1. Run `flutter upgrade` in the terminal to upgrade Flutter
2. Run `dart migrate` to run the dart migration tool.
3. Solve all errors which the migration tool shows.
4. Run `flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety` to print all outdated packages.
5. Run `flutter pub upgrade --null-safety` to upgrade all packages automatically.
6. **Check the code for errors and solve them** (Very important).
7. Run `dart migrate` again and it should now be successful. Follow the link to checkout the proposed changes.
8. Press the "Apply Migration" button.
9. Check the code for errors again and fix them.

Your project should be updated now.
Referenced from this [website](https://www.felixlarsen.com/blog/update-your-flutter-project-to-flutter-20).

Comment: Best Answer, because it's the simplest and easiest way described.

Comment: This did the trick for me. In my case I needed to upgrade manually android build tool:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
...and gradle distributionUrl: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Answer (score 8):

Go ro the root directory of your flutter project and run **flutter upgrade**. This will upgrade both your existing flutter project and flutter SDK to latest version.

Run the command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

**Additional for upgrading to latest stable version only**

If you want to upgrade to latest version only then please first check your current flutter channel

**Step 1**:
Check for Stable channel

```
flutter channel
```

You will get output like this:

```
  beta
  dev
  master
* stable
```

If output was not like this then please proceed to Step 2 or directly proceed to Step 3

**Step 2**:
Switch to flutter stable channel

```
flutter channel stable
```

Now you will get output like this:

```
  beta
  dev
  master
* stable
```

**Step 3**:
Run the below command to upgrade to latest stable version of flutter

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I understand this. But isn't this upgrade the SDK? How about the app itself? I come from the .NET background, where an application can target which version of the framework that it wants to build against. Does Flutter not work that way, does it always build against the SDK version? Can it be built using specific version?

Comment: @user1491884 I would like to know this as well.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I want to updated the app itself without touching the flutter SDK. I come from an Angular background where you can update the app's local Angular version while leaving the globally installed version untouched.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your  project root, run below command

```
flutter upgrade
```

This command will update the Flutter SDK locally installed on your workstation, wondering how does that make sense?

After you run, above command `flutter upgrade` the SDK is updated locally and whenever you build or run your flutter app now, it should always pick up the latest stable version (stable channel) installed locally.

to check run,

```
flutter channel
```

you should get something like below based on what version is installed locally on your workstation.

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d7946a68d (3 days ago) • 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
Engine • revision 3459eb2436
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
```

You can always switch to a different channel with below command,

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

***Answer to - the Flutter SDK locally installed on your workstation, wondering how does that make sense?***

Open your pubspec.yml file and see below:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

1. Where version: 1.0.0+1 is your flutter app version
2. When you run command `flutter run` your app should pick up the environment as defined which is `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"`
3. With all dependencies as defined under,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

where `sdk: flutter` states that the SDK should be pulled from your locally installed SDK version.

Recall, how you had installed the Flutter SDK first time, on your local workstation, as below MAC example, See all [SDK releases](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

```
cd ~/development
unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_2.0.3-stable.zip
```

later, Update your path, and run `flutter doctor`.

**OR**

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
```

later, Update your path, and run `flutter doctor`.

Note: You may check your pubspec.lock file that may look like below,

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.12.0-0.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.16.0" <---- Use SDK greater than this installed locally
```

Answer (score 1):

**I will show you an easy way to migrate old code projects.**

My recommendation is not to work on the existing old project. Instead, create a new project where you can turn your existing project code into new clean, tidy code at a time.

Now put a line of code on the existing old code project terminal as below.

```
$ flutter create -t <project-type> <new-project-path>
```

For example, your terminal code like,

```
PS C:\Users\habib\VScodeProject\git_ripository\simple-weather-old> flutter create -t app C:\Users\habib\VScodeProject\git_ripository\simple-weather-new
```

Done.
After that, Your new project will no more show any system problems, like `gradle` problems, android manifesto problems i.e.

If you want to see more about flutter migrating: [[See this flutter doc]](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/androidx-migration#what-if-i-cant-use-android-studio)

Comment: I've been trying to avoid this option like the plague, but given how much time I've spent trying to fix all these dang Gradle issues, etc., .. -sigh- .. I am now thinking that this is The Way.

Answer (score 0):

> To update to the latest compatible versions of all the dependencies listed in the pubspec.yaml file, use the upgrade command:`flutter pub upgrade`

> To update to the latest possible version of all the dependencies listed in the pubspec.yaml file, use the upgrade --major-versions command:
> `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

After I run the first command my flutter version in pubspec.lock changed to

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=3.2.0 <
  flutter: ">=3.16.0"
```

which is currently the latest stable version. Before it was 3.3.0.

Read more [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade#upgrading-packages)

Answer (score -1):

if you upgrade your project, but still have problem. then please check your path spellin is ok or not!?

I also face this problem. after upgrading project it won't work for me. then i look to my code, there was miss path.