# Flutter pub get Flutter version mismatch | podfile.lock flutter version mismatch

Tags: ios, flutter, podfile, flutter-ios, podfile-lock

I have updated my flutter version to `3.0.1` - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797607/how-do-i-upgrade-an-existing-flutter-app)

I have one existing flutter project. When I hit `flutter pub get` command, inside `ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec` file, it is showing flutter version 1.0.0.

> s.version          = '1.0.0'

Also in the iOS `podfile.lock` file is also showing `flutter version 1.0.0`. I tried updating pod, etc everything but same issue.

> PODS:
>
> - Flutter (1.0.0)

Why it is showing 1.0.0 instead of 3.0.1. or this is not the correct way to check & update flutter version of existing project?

Answer (score 0):

The flutter version depends on your environment (not the project), so you should be able to just run `flutter --version` to see which version you're running.

As for the project, it should normally build with any compatible flutter version. If you look at your `pubspec.yaml`, it should have the `environment` part which specifies the SDK. It should look something like the following to be compatible with the new Flutter version:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.0.0'
```

I think (not entirely sure, though) that the 1.0.0 that you see is the app version, as specified in the `pubspec.yaml` version (usually right above the environment bit).