# How to upgrade flutter project dart sdk version

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Flutter version 3.3.2 installed.
How do I upgrade flutter project dart sdk version?

Current project sdk version
sdk:">=2.7.0 3.0.0<"

Answer (score 3):

You can run `flutter upgrade` and normally your project should pick up the most recent version of the SDK.
Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) and to this previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797607/how-do-i-upgrade-an-existing-flutter-app).