# old flutter project, flutter_localizations problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations, flutter-intl

I have a problem with running an older flutter project on my windows machine. 
flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1848], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.80.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml packages

```
version: 1.0.3+8
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  ...
  intl: 0.17.0
  ...
```

error message

```
flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Because psxmpc depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.0, intl 0.18.0 is required.
So, because psxmpc depends on intl 0.17.0, version solving failed.
exit code 1
```

this error basically happens when trying to run an older flutter project on my device and i have the latest flutter version.

**Update**
and when trying to update the intl to 0.18.0
this other error happens with another package on my project flutter_paystack

```
[PSX-Multipurpose-Classified] flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Because flutter_paystack >=1.0.5 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and psxmpc depends on intl 0.18.0, flutter_paystack >=1.0.5 is forbidden.
So, because psxmpc depends on flutter_paystack 1.0.7, version solving failed.
exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously many packages nowadays depend on `intl`. We should upgrade packages & Flutter to the latest version. Consider to read about migrate:

- [How do I upgrade an existing Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797607/how-do-i-upgrade-an-existing-flutter-app)
- https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes
- https://codewithandrea.com/tips/dart-fix-apply/

If you are lazy, just download another downgrade version of Flutter or using [fvm](https://fvm.app/) to easily switch Flutter version.

Comment: I took the easy solution